# Calculate the circle area etc. (loop)

Tags: c++

result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bck0p.jpg)

since I learn loop a few days,
I don't understand how to use the loop to do so 
especially the protocol loop parts 
can anyone help?

my code: [enter link description here](http://cpp.sh/5u3pu)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const double PI = 3.14159265;
void circle(int r1, int r2, double &d, double &c, double &a)
for(int i=r1;i<=r2;i++)
{
    {
    d=2*i;
    c=2*PI*i;
    a=PI*i*i;
    }
 }

 int main(){
 double d, c, a;

 int r1, r2;
 int r;
 cout<<"enter 1st no.";
 cin>>r1;
 cout<<"enter 2nd no.";
 cin>>r2;

 cout << endl;
 cout << setw(6) << "Radius";
 cout << setw(10) << "Diameter";
 cout << setw(15) << "Circumference";
 cout << setw(10) << "Area" << endl;

 circle(r1, r2, d, c, a);
 for (int i=r1;i<=r2; i++)
 {
     cout<< setw(6)<<i<< setw(10)<<d<< setw(15)<<c<< setw(10)<<a<<endl;
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "protocol loop parts" ? What dont you understand? Is there a compiler error? What should this code do what it isnt doing?

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: the code work but I really dont know to calculate the diameter, Circumference and area by using loop.

Comment: ‘*the code work*’ No, that's not possible. It doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to surround the implemention of `circle` with `{}`.
- You will have to update the results *inside* the loop to print.
- `circle` won't need loop.
- Correct format to match the sample.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const double PI = 3.14159265;
void circle(int i, double &d, double &c, double &a){
    d=2*i;
    c=2*PI*i;
    a=PI*i*i;
}

int main(){
    double d, c, a;

    int r1, r2;
    int r;
    cout<<"Please enter the starting radius: ";
    cin>>r1;
    cout<<"Please enter the ending radius: ";
    cin>>r2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(6) << "Radius";
    cout << setw(10) << "Diameter";
    cout << setw(15) << "Circumference";
    cout << setw(10) << "Area" << endl;

    for (int i=r1;i<=r2; i++)
    {
        circle(i, d, c, a);
        cout<< fixed<<setprecision(2)<<setw(6)<<i<< setw(10)<<d<< setw(15)<<c<< setw(10)<<a<<endl;
    }
    cout << "Press any key to continue . . ." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```